# How to know whether JSF bean setter is invoked from AJAX event or as part of form POST processing

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a form that contains a Part Number inputText field and some other fields that represent the attributes of a part.  If the user enters an existing part number, I want to populate the other fields with the part's existing attributes.  The operator then has the option to change Part Number to something else (essentially creating a new part using the existing part as a template) and/or modify its attributes.  I have an AJAX event defined to update the model when Part Number changes, so I can retrieve the attributes from the database:

```
<f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" render="partlength" />
```

My question is this:  How does the Part Number setter (e.g. setPartNumber() ) know whether it is being invoked as part of an AJAX event, in which case I want to fetch the attributes, or as part of the Update Model Values phase of the form being posted, in which case I don't?  Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine by [`PartialViewContext#isAjaxRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#isAjaxRequest%28%29) whether the current request is an ajax request or not. You can obtain the [`PartialViewContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html) by [`FacesContext#getPartialViewContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getPartialViewContext%28%29).

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
    // The current request is an ajax request.
}
```

An alternative is to just do the job in the `listener` method of `<f:ajax>` instead of in the getter/setter (doing business job in getters/setters is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times) anyway):

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="partlength" />
```

*(note that I omitted the `event` and `execute` attributes as you've used the default values already)*

Comment: Thanks.  I had a gut feeling there was a better way to do it since it didn't seem to be flowing well.